# tableview cells bleeding though each other

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

i have a UITableview with one reusable cell. The reusable cell contains a photo and a label. right now there are 7 items in my table view. upon loading, everthing is fine. but when i scroll down, and then scroll back up, the cells have bled into one another.

Here is my code under cellforRowatIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as! PostTableCellView

    cell.imageView!.image = posts[indexPath.row].image.value


    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    post.downloadImage()
    post.fetchLikes()
    cell.post = post

    cell.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.viewforphoto.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}
```

any idea what could be happening? i have rebuilt the storyboard now and the problem persists. I have also changed the view mode of the image view and the table view cell to aspect fit, aspect fill and scale to fill. looking at other similar questions led me to see if setting clipstoBounds = true would help, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are downloading right in the middle of `cellforRowatIndexPath:`. There's no time for that. The user is scrolling *now*. You must return the cell *now*. *Now!* You cannot be fetching data remotely or performing any other time-consuming task. You must have every requested cell's data ready to hand *instantly*.

Comment: thanks a lot! yes that was the problem! I'm not sure why this has been down voted so much, but anyways thanks for the help.